# Order in Array of K8s entity

Tags: kubernetes, yaml

I have CRD (Custom Resource Definition) with a field with a type "array". I wonder if in this array the order is preserved , mens , if i apply yaml with:

```
myField:
- a
- b
- c
```

And after that I get the entity using kubectl, it is promised to me that I get the order I mentions before and nor

```
myField:
- b
- a
- c
```

Comment: the order is not guaranteed, but you shouldn't care about it.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, YAML sequences are ordered and preserve order across parsing and serialization.  From [YAML 1.2 §3.2.1.1](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2764044) (emphasis in original):

> The content of a *sequence* node is an ordered series of zero or more nodes.

This is contrast to mapping nodes, which are unordered.

```yaml
guaranteedToPreserveOrder: # a sequence of mappings with name: keys
  - name: a
    value: one
  - name: b
    value: two
notGuaranteedToPreserveOrder: # a simple mapping
  a: one
  b: two
```

Comment: I don't ask about yaml format, I ask about k8s: if k8s save order in its internal storage and cannot  change the order

Answer (score 0):

> I don't ask about yaml format, I ask about k8s: if k8s save order in
>   its internal storage and cannot change the order

**lists/arrays** in yaml manifests are like **lists** in Python which basically are collections of **ordered** and changeable (mutable) elements. And yes, **kubernetes also stores them following this rule**.

You can easily check it by performing a simple test. It's not a working example of nginx server as all ports are fictitious, but it illustrates pretty well the idea:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.14.2
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5
        - containerPort: 4
        - containerPort: 3
        - containerPort: 2
        - containerPort: 1
```

Once you deploy it on your k8s cluster by running `kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml` you can retrieve it by making a call to kube-api server e.g. by using:

```
kubectl get deployment nginx-deployment -o yaml
```

which gives you the following output:

```
...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 4
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 3
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 2
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 1
...
```

As you can see all elements of our list are stored in the same order as they were listed in our `yaml` manifest. You can try to put those elements in completely different order and you'll see that kubernetes won't sort them in any way. The order of the elements of the list will always be kept.